# How do I execute QTcpSocket in a different thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, tcp, qt4

How do I execute QTcpSocket functions in a different thread?

Comment: **It's not possible**. I have learned this hard way. See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60019664/514235). Have raised a bug-suggestion to Qt to `moveToThread () = delete` for these sockets and server classes. [QTBUG-82373](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-82373)

Answer (score 11):

It's important to note what you can and can't do in terms of threading `QTcpSocket`:

- you **can** use it in a non-main thread, but only *the thread in which it was created in.*
- you **cannot** call different functions on the `QTcpSocket` from different threads, e.g. read in one thread, write in the other. Instead, you can make a seperate thread for each `QTcpSocket`, which keeps them from using up time and resources that could be painting your widgets in the main thread.

IMO, putting your IO, including `QTcpSocket` in a thread other than the main thread is a best practice and must-do for any performant application. I use `QTcpSocket` in non-main threads all the time using the following idiom:

```cpp
// Read data from a QTcpSocket in a thread. Assumes this is in some class.
m_thread = std::thread([this]
{
    QEventLoop eventLoop;
    QTcpSocket* socket = new QTcpSocket(&eventLoop);

    socket->connectToHost("localhost", 9999);

    // enqueue or process the data
    QObject::connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, &eventLoop, [socket]
    {

        m_concurrentQueue.push_back(socket->readAll());
    });

    // Quit the loop (and thread) if the socket it disconnected. You could also try
    // reconnecting
    QObject::connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, &eventLoop, [&eventLoop]
    {
        eventLoop.quit();
    });

    eventLoop.exec();

    delete socket;
});
```

where `m_thread` is some member thread (basically just ensuring that it has a lifetime greater than the current immediate scope), and `m_concurrentQueue` is some thread-safe queue, or `std` container with mutex protection.

You'll also want to connect some signal (I usually call it `joinAll`) to the event loop quit function, and call it from the class destructor. When using an event-loop-in-a-thread idiom you always have to be careful about making sure you can actually destroy the class correctly, otherwise your program won't exit (or on windows it will be terminated, usually with some destructors not getting called, and it ends up being a silent error).

I also usually use a condition variable to wait after creating the thread until the event loop has started. It's not necessary but if you are putting these threads together in constructors it can help make the program flow make more sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already upvoted on the day you posted. I had found this fact hard way that the `QTcpSocket` or `QWebSocket` are not thread-movable! Have raised a bug to Qt on this regard and put it under the question above.

Comment: @Nicolas, this solution looks great but I wounder how to handle data of `m_concurrentQueue` in main thread, I mean should I use `QTimer` or just signal to notify main thread to start handle queues data? Which variant is the best in terms of performance? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you use a lambda for eventLoop.quit instead of  `&QEventLoop::quit`?

Comment: @cdgraham I don't think so, probably copied it from something that did some cleanup on exit.

Answer (score 8):

The QT docs are explicit that the `QTCPSocket` should not be used accross threads.  I.E, create a `QTCPSocket` in the main thread and have the signal tied to an object in another thread.

I suspect that you are implementing something like a web server where the listen creates a `QTCPSocket` on the accept.  You then want another thread to handle the task of processing that socket.  You can't.

The way I worked around it is I kept the socket in the thread it was born in.  I serviced all of the incoming data in that thread and threw it into a queue where another thread could work on that data.

#### [`virtual void incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#incomingConnection)

> Note: If another socket is created in the reimplementation of this method, it needs to be added to the Pending Connections mechanism by calling `addPendingConnection()`.
>
> Note: If you want to handle an incoming connection as a new `QTcpSocket` object in another thread you have to **pass the `socketDescriptor` to the other thread and create the `QTcpSocket` object there** and use its `setSocketDescriptor()` method.

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: That note was added by the community, and in my emperical experience is not correct. Nor does it seem you can simulate the behavior by passing socket descriptors as they claim, since you end up with two `QTcpSocket` instances (the implicit child of the server and the instance you create in the new thread) running on the same descriptor, which causes run-time assertion failures.

Comment: You say you "serviced all of the incoming data in that thread and threw it into a queue where another thread could work on that data." How do you do this?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus, added a note backing up the answer. I am also facing a crash where I move a `QTcpSocket` created in a main thread to another worker thread. Upon checking the stack-trace, it appears that the main thread still retains some object of type `QSslSocketBackendPrivate` which writes the data. This causes the crash. In past I was misunderstanding this situation and was blaming the issue on my coding error. But it seems there is something wrong with the Qt library. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60019664/514235). What is the correct way to move a TCP socket to another thread?

Comment: @iammilind it's best not to move them, but to *create* them in a different thread. I added an answer showing the idiom I use to do it.

Answer (score 2):

What I read in the docs is that [QTcpSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html) should not be used across threads. If you want to use it in another thread Qt docs say you should create a new QTcpSocket instance in your thread and set the descriptor on the new instance. To do this you need to reimplement QTcpServer and use [QTcpServer::incomingConnection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#incomingConnection). A simple example is provided [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html).

Answer (score 1):

Put a `QMutex` lock around all calls, not just on the "different" thread but on all threads. One easy way to do so is via a `QMutexLocker`

Comment: ["**Note:** All functions in this class are reentrant"](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qtcpsocket.html). If you have a more authoritative source for your contradicting claim, please include that.

Comment: You're right. However, (and what I meant to say was) the class is not thread-safe, and the re-entrancy only guarantees you can use the class from multiple threads if you have different instances, but different `QTcpSocket` instances cannot share socket descriptors. Additionally, a single instance of a `QTcpSocket` cannot be accessed from multiple threads, regardless of whether it is mutexed.

Answer (score 0):

`QTcpSocket` and `QUdpSocket` cannot be moved to a different thread once they have been "opened". This is not supported by Qt and (mostly) doesn't work.

While they can be moved when they are in the "closed" state, that's not generally particularly useful.

What you should do is either:

1. Create the socket inside the thread it will be used in and use signals to marshal the data to be sent/received between threads.
2. Pass a `socketDescriptor` from the thread that starts opening the connection across to the thread where the socket should live, and open the socket *there* using the `socketDescriptor`.

Common gotchas:

When using `QTcpServer`, it will open QTcpSockets in the same thread as itself. As they're already open, they cannot be moved.

If you want `QTcpServer` to open incoming sockets in a different worker thread to the server itself (very common!), you must subclass it and override [`QTcpServer::incomingConnection()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcpserver.html#incomingConnection) to get access to the socket descriptor *before* it creates a `QTcpSocket`. You cannot use the default implementation.

If you are subclassing `QThread`, *do not* create the sockets in the constructor. They must be created in `QThread::run()`