# Qt - Handle QTcpSocket in a new thread

Tags: c++, qt

Trying to handle a connected client socket in a new thread from global thread pool:

```
m_threadPool = QThreadPool::globalInstance();

void TCPListenerThread::onNewConnection()
{
    QTcpSocket *clientSocket = m_tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
    clientSocket->localPort();
    m_connectThread = new TCPConnectThread(clientSocket);
    m_threadPool->start(m_connectThread);
}
```

Here's `TCPConnectThread`:

```
class TCPConnectThread : public QRunnable {
    TCPConnectThread::TCPConnectThread(QTcpSocket *_socket)
    {
        m_socket = _socket;
        this->setAutoDelete(false);
    }


    void TCPConnectThread::run()
    {
        if (! m_socket->waitForConnected(-1) )
            qDebug("Failed to connect to client");
        else
            qDebug("Connected to %s:%d %s:%d", m_socket->localAddress(), m_socket->localPort(), m_socket->peerAddress(), m_socket->peerPort());

        if (! m_socket->waitForReadyRead(-1))
            qDebug("Failed to receive message from client") ;
        else
            qDebug("Read from client: %s",   QString(m_socket->readAll()).toStdString().c_str());

        if (! m_socket->waitForDisconnected(-1))
            qDebug("Failed to receive disconnect message from client");
        else
            qDebug("Disconnected from client");
    }
}
```

I have been getting endless errors with these. It seems cross-thread `QTcpSocket` handling is [not feasible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698145/how-do-i-execute-qtcpsocket-in-a-different-thread)(See Michael's answer).

Some errors:

```
QSocketNotifier: socket notifiers cannot be disabled from another thread  

ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events t objects owned by a different thread.
```

Should I handle `QTcpSocket` in a different thread ?
What should I do if I want to handle `QTcpSocket` in a different thread ?
Or is there way to create a `QTcpSocket` from a file descriptor ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [this page](http://qt-project.org/doc/note_revisions/33/54/view) holds your answer:

> If you want to handle an incoming connection as a new QTcpSocket
>   object in another thread you have to pass the socketDescriptor to the
>   other thread and create the QTcpSocket object there and use its
>   setSocketDescriptor() method.

To do this, you'll have to inherit from `QTcpServer` and override the virtual method [`incomingConnection`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtcpserver.html#incomingConnection).

Within that method, create the child thread which will create a new `QTcpSocket` for the child socket.

For example:

```
class MyTcpServer : public QTcpServer
{
protected:
    virtual void incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)
    {
         TCPConnectThread* clientThread = new TCPConnectThread(socketDescriptor);
         // add some more code to keep track of running clientThread instances...
         m_threadPool->start(clientThread);
    }
};

class TCPConnectThread : public QRunnable
{
private:    
    int m_socketDescriptor;
    QScopedPointer<QTcpSocket> m_socket;

public:
    TCPConnectionThread(int socketDescriptor)
        : m_socketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)
    {
        setAutoDelete(false);
    }

protected:    
    void TCPConnectThread::run()
    {
        m_socket.reset(new QTcpSocket());
        m_socket->setSocketDescriptor(m_socketDescriptor);

        // use m_socket
    }
};
```

or try to use `moveToThread()` on the socket.

Comment: moveToThread() seems only work with QThread but I'm using QRunnable.

Comment: then try to pass the `socketDescriptor` to the `TCPConnectThread` constructor and create a new `QTcpSocket` in the threads `run` method.

Comment: Really thanks ! But I found that sometimes I would fail to read data from the new QTcpSocket, about 1 in 10 times. Do you see why ?

Comment: Here's the output of my program:  Read from client: Data
Disconnected from client
Connected to client
Read from client: Data
Disconnected from client
Connected to client
Read from client: Data
Disconnected from client
Connected to client
Read from client: [failed]
Disconnected from client

Comment: do you mean `m_socket->readAll()` actually returns the string `[failed]`? If so, then that is what it has received. Anyway, you should call `waitForReadyRead` and `readAll` in a loop until you have all the data you need. Otherwise it is very likely that `waitForReadyRead` will return when only a part of the expected data is in the read buffer. It will not read your mind to determine when incoming data is complete ;)

Comment: No, it doesn't return a thing. I replaced with `[failed]`...  What should I do if I want to read all the data with one `waitForReadyRead` ? Is this possible ?

Comment: Block the thread for 30 seconds first? Seriously, this would be a very bad design. So: use a loop and add some code that decides when to disconnect the client.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Yup, looks great now!