# Why am I getting runtime errors, with Sockets (TCP/Web) when moved to another thread? Is `QObject::moveToThread()` a synchronous call?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets, qsslsocket

I am moving some sockets from main thread to worker thread and processing `readyRead()`, `close()`, `write()` etc. on the new thread. Rarely I see below dangerous warning:

> *"QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread"*

Usually the execution after this warning results in undefined behaviour (crash / uncaught exception / normal).
Have checked all the signal/slot to the socket and they seem proper. From my experience, usually the above warning will be frequent or quick if there is any coding irregularity.

Now I am suspecting if `moveToThread()` does its job as expected or not! Because from [QEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum) documentation a `QEvent::ThreadChange` is raised as the last event on the current thread during this function call.

> The object is moved to another thread. This is the last event sent to this object in the previous thread. See [`QObject::moveToThread()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread)<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dn3q.png)</sup>.
>   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Dn3q.png) A `QEvent::ThreadChange` event is sent to this object just before the thread affinity is changed. You can handle this event to perform any special processing.

In my code, I am not checking for this event. Rather I assume that, once the `moveToThread()` is finished, the thread affinity is changed and the new "signal/slot" on the object is guaranteed on the new thread.

**Question**:

1. Is it safe to move the sockets to another thread?
2. Will `moveToThread()` assure that the signals on that object are also moved to the new thread just after this function?
3. How should it be designed to assure no threading irregularity with Sockets?

---

BTW, in the latest Qt debugger it lands on following code segment:

```
// qsocketnotifier.cpp
if (Q_UNLIKELY(thread() != QThread::currentThread())) {
    qWarning("QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread");
    return;
}
```

Below is the stack frame for the main thread:
[image]

Below is the stack frame for the worker thread, which halts on the logging:
[image]

Comment: If you create an object in thread A, then you need to call moveToThread() from thread A, not from any other thread.

Comment: @user1095108, that's how it has been done all across the code

Comment: You've proved yourself, that that's not the case somehow. The warning wouldn't trigger otherwise.

Comment: While not directly asked, you should also be aware that how you connect to a thread will make a difference to how an emitted message is delivered to the thread. If you use a Qt::DirectConnection the emit of a signal will make an immediate call to the slot IN THE CONTEXT OF THE EMIT and is blocking. Using Qt::QueuedConnection allows the thread context to be changed before delivery and is non-blocking.  See [Qt's Connection Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Qt sockets are NOT supported with `moveToThread()` idiom!!!

I wish Qt had documented this fact as LOUD as above. I have spent weeks of debugging an issue which is not meant for fixing. Socket `moveToThread()` issue is so complicated, that it doesn't happen consistently. I could reproduce it consistently only after testing a customised `QTcpServer` subclass with lots of socket open/close scenario.

Later I came across this post: [How do I execute QTcpSocket in a different thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698145/how-do-i-execute-qtcpsocket-in-a-different-thread). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706898/514235) explicitly states that sockets are not supported for the movement across the threads.

Here are the documentations from [`QTcpServer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#incomingConnection)

> **Note**: The returned `QTcpSocket` object cannot be used from another thread. If you want to use an incoming connection from another thread, you need to override `incomingConnection()`.
>
> **Note**: If you want to handle an incoming connection as a new `QTcpSocket` object in another thread you have to pass the "socketDescriptor" to the other thread and create the `QTcpSocket` object there and use its `setSocketDescriptor()` method.

Probably this will apply to the `QWebSocketServer` too!

---

So the best approach is to overload `incomingConnection()` and call its internal in another thread.

```
void MyTcpServer::incomingConnection (qintptr socketDescriptor) override
{
  emit SignalToDifferentThread(socketDescriptor);
}
```

If done so, the `addPendingConnection()` and `nextPendingConnection()` idiom may not be required, even though it's mentioned in a note.

> **Note**: If another socket is created in the reimplementation of this method, it needs to be added to the Pending Connections mechanism by calling `addPendingConnection()`.  <sub>(<-- this may not apply for the sockets in different thread)</sub>

---

#### `QWebSocketServer` is stricter than `QTcpServer`

This is another fact, which wasted more time for me. In `QTcpServer`, we can overload the `incomingConnection()` and pass on the socket descriptor to another thread to create a socket. However, `QWebSocketServer` doesn't have such overload. Mostly because, `QSslSocket` received in `QTcpServer` gets upgraded to `QWebSocket` and passed on to the `QWebSocketServer` via its `handleConnection()` method.

So **`QWebSocket` must be created where `QWebSocketServer` resides!**. Hence in whichever threads, we want a `QWebSocket` to be created, all those threads need to have an object of `QWebSocketServer`. Idiomatically we can have one `QTcpServer` listening on a single port and can keep passing its `QTcpSocket`s (upgraded to `QWebSocket`s) to these various threads' `QWebSocketServer`s in a load balancing way.

---

#### A message to Qt developers

I wish that, you can save lot of time of the developers relying on the Qt library by a simple compilation error. This will negate all the wrong articles floating around internet which suggest how to use `moveToThread()` on a `QTcpSocket`. Just introduce below method:

```
class QTcpServer / QTcpSocket / QWebSocketServer / QWebSocket : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  ...
  // Create this object in a desired thread instead of moving
  private: void moveToThread (QThread*) = delete; // hiding `QObject::moveToThread()`
};
```

**Update**: Raised [QTBUG-82373](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-82373).

Answer (score 0):

A quote from the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread), that provides the answer:

> Warning: This function is not thread-safe; the current thread must be
>   same as the current thread affinity. In other words, **this function can
>   only "push" an object from the current thread to another thread**, it
>   cannot "pull" an object from any arbitrary thread to the current
>   thread. There is one exception to this rule however: objects with no
>   thread affinity can be "pulled" to the current thread.